# Multi slideshow for listings not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

The first two listings work perfectly, especially if I remove the third and fourth from the code. The third listing doesn't show any images where it should, and the fourth shows all the images at once, until you click the next button, then they all disappear also.

Image of the webpage:

[image: image of the web page]

This is my main element that contains the listings

```html
<main>
    <h2>Latest Listings</h2>
    <div class="main-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mySlides1">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="images/home1.1.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides1">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="images/home1.2.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides1">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="images/home1.3.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>

            <div class="caption-container"><p>$608 / 3br - Townhouse</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="mySlides2">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home2.1.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home2.2.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home2.3.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home2.4.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides2">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home2.5.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>

            <div class="caption-container"><p>$685 / Fully Furnished, Beautiful 1-Bedroom Apt.</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.1.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.2.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.3.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.4.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.5.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides3">
                <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
                <img src="images/home3.6.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 2)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1, 2)">&#10095;</button>

            <div class="caption-container"><p>$1,000 / 2 Bedroom, 2 Bath Apartment DUPLEX</p></div>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mySlides4">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home4.1.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides4">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home4.2.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides4">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home4.3.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides4">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home4.4.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides4">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                <img src="images/home4.5.jpg" alt="home demo image">
            </div>

            <button class="prev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 3)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="next" onclick="plusDivs(1, 3)">&#10095;</button>

            <div class="caption-container"><p>$700 / Remodeled 2BR 1 BA with large yard</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

Below is the javascript I used to cycle through the images in each slideshow

```js
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4"];
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);
showDivs(1, 3);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
    showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

This is the CSS being used:

```css
main img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.main-gallery {
  width: 120%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #555;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.prev:focus,
.next:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

I am not sure what I did to make it not work, and I have spent days trying to find the mistake. That is why I am hoping someone can point out my error. Let me know if you need any other information to help.

Comment: can you provide CSS?

Comment: I just updated it with the css for that section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote requires you to add a new value of "1" to the "slideIndex" array for each slideshow

Replace

```
var slideIndex = [1, 1]
```

with this:

```
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1, 1];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.